# Maven-publish with multi-platform runtime dependencies

Tags: java, maven, gradle, lwjgl, maven-publish

I'm trying to publish a Java library that has native runtime dependencies (LWJGL) - this is done by stating a classifier to determine which native binaries to include (for eg. Windows, Linux, etc).

Gradle example:

```
api group: "org.lwjgl", name: "lwjgl", version: lwjglVersion
runtimeOnly group: "org.lwjgl", name: "lwjgl", version: lwjglVersion, classifier: "natives-linux"
```

I'm wondering the best way to publish **my library** artifacts (Maven Central using the maven-publish gradle plugin) which is built on top of those.

I could generate a different artifact-id per each native classifier (for eg. mylib-linux:1.0.0 or mylib-windows:1.0.0) but that seems non-optimal - this happens because the .POM is automatically filled with whatever runtime classifier is assigned while executing the publish task.

Current way of importing my library:

```
api group: "io.my", name: "mylib-windows", version: "1.0"
```

Intended:

```
api group: "io.my", name: "mylib", version: "1.0", classifier: "windows"
```

Is there any way to make the dependency classifiers dynamic based on my lib classifier (for example with transitive classifiers values instead of hard-coded ones)?

My publish task:

```
    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                groupId '<group-id>'
                artifactId project.name
                version rootProject.version

                from components.java

                artifact(sourceJar) {
                    classifier = 'sources'
                }

                artifact(javadocJar) {
                    classifier = 'javadoc'
                }

                pom {
                    name = '<my-project-name>'
                    description = '<my-project-description>.'
                    url = '<my-project-url>'
                    developers {
                        developer {
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                    scm {
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think feature variants may help, although not entirely sure since have not used them myself: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/feature_variants.html